# GAMS: Double Exponent in Objective Function

Tags: solver, gams-math

I want to include a function in the objective function that requires the objective to be squared first, multiplied with its probability, and then squared with the inverse again.

I tried the following function to figure it out:

(power((sum(t,  CEMUTOTPER(t))),2))**0.5

How can I make sure that I get the same result as sum(t,  CEMUTOTPER(t))? The squared function above messes it up even though it should mathematically be the same as sum(t,  CEMUTOTPER(t))?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactly you intend in your first line. It doesn't sound exactly the same as the second part. Be careful with negative bases. https://support.gams.com/gams:difference_between_the_-operator_and_the_power_function This might be useful for you.

Comment: Hey, I try to include recursive preferences in a model. For that, I need to apply an objective function that looks like this: (beta*(((pA*(acertainty)**alpha)+(pB*(bcertainty**alpha)))**(rho/alpha))). That gives me the error message with the negative base. But I get that error message even if just square the simplified form with 2 and then with 0.5, which mathematically is just an exponent of 1. So I'm not sure what the solver does?

Comment: The point above was that you'll need to use `power` if you have a negative base.

Comment: But that is the thing, it shouldn´t be a negative base. If I run the base case without the two exponents, I get a positive value. So true, it could be that I got a negative base with two exponents. But this shouldn´t be, so I tested it with the exp(2) and exp(0.5) function to see what happens as they mathematically just cancel out. And this gives me also the negative exponent error, even though it should give the same result as the base case.

Comment: If your base is changing from positive to negative when you simply square and square root, it suggests your error is somewhere else.

Comment: Apologies for being so ignorant here, but if I use the power function power((sum(t, CEMUTOTPER(t))),1)), I get the same result as in the standard case (sum(t, CEMUTOTPER(t))). In the standard case, the "base" is positive. However, if I use ((sum(t, CEMUTOTPER(t)))**1, I get the error message with the negative base. Doesn´t that have anything to do with the way the solver optimizes the model?

Comment: I don't see why it would in principle, but without more detail on cemutotper and the rest of the model I'm not sure how much more help I can offer.

Comment: That's the objective function from the standard DICE model (https://sites.google.com/site/williamdnordhaus/dice-rice). It maximizes the utility of the sum of the separate period utilities: 
cemutotpereq(t)..    CEMUTOTPER(t)  =E= PERIODU(t) * L(t) * rr(t);
 periodueq(t)..       PERIODU(t)     =E= ((C(T)*1000/L(T))**(1-elasmu)-1)/(1-elasmu)-1;

I also get this message (even if I just use **1):

 ** Domain error(s) in nonlinear functions.
    Check bounds on variables.

Comment: Try this: https://forum.gamsworld.org/viewtopic.php?t=7770

Comment: `a**b` is basically evaluated as `exp(b*log(a))` so `a` should be larger than 0. As variables may be some epsilon tolerance outside their bounds, it may make sense to add a small number: `(...+TOL)**y` with `TOL=1.e-5` (say). Alternatively, use an intermediate variable with a lowerbound of TOL.

Comment: Okay, when I define (sum(t, CEMUTOTPER(t))) as a nonnegative variable, then  (sum(t, CEMUTOTPER(t)))**1 results in the same as  (sum(t, CEMUTOTPER(t))). But still, if I then check and maximize ((sum(t, CEMUTOTPER(t)))**2)**0.5, it completely messes up the output. How is that possible?

Comment: and if I test the objective function (sum(t, CEMUTOTPER(t)))**1.00001, it results in an objective of 0